# Ubuntu One Music Streaming API - getIndexes.view only returning a subset of artists

Tags: ubuntu-one-api

I'm writing an Ubuntu One client for Haiku for a student project, currently implementing the music streaming bit.  I'm only getting 52 artists in the response for getIndexes.view in the XML response, but I get 119 artists in the Android client and the web client.

The request is called as:

```
GET https://streaming.one.ubuntu.com/rest/getIndexes.view?u=xxxxxx&p=xxxxxx&v=1.2.0&c=haiku
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: What format is your music in?  Might there only be 52 artists with music in MP3 with the rest in Vorbis, for instance?

Comment: Aha! Yes, exactly that.  So, would it be something to do with the client string determining supported formats?

Comment: Update: OK, so changing c=haiku to c=android and I get all the Vorbis files returned as well.  Is there a server side setting you can change that says 'haiku' as a client can support Vorbis?  Thanks, Chris

Answer (score 0):

By default, Ubuntu One's Subsonic API implementation will only return MP3s, which is why some of your music is not being returned.  This is done since we can't rely on clients supporting other formats.

If you change your client ID to start with `ubuntu` (e.g. use `ubuntu-haiku` instead of `haiku`), the server will assume you know how to handle Vorbis files too.